# Добавление новой строки в раздел файла конфигурации без его перезаписи с помощью ConfigParser

Tags: python, ini

Помогите решить проблему с новой строкой.
Как добавлять новый раздел разобрался, но с добавлением новой строки не перезаписывая раздел уперся в штангу. ConfigParser

Конфиг:

```
[General]
fbrightlightcolorb = 1.0000
fbrightlightcolorg = 1.0000
fbrightlightcolorr = 1.0000
istorymanagerloggingevent = -1
```

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import configparser
import os


# Создаю файл
def get_config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.write(open('example.ini', 'w'))
        # Если нет файла, создаем
    if not os.path.exists('example.ini'):
        config.read('example.ini')

        with open('example.ini', "w") as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)

    config.read('example.ini')
    return config

# Набиваю файл инфой
def create_config():

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.add_section("General")
    config.set("General", "fBrightLightColorB", "1.0000")
    config.set("General", "fBrightLightColorG", "1.0000")
    config.set("General", "fBrightLightColorR", "1.0000")
    config.set("General", "iStoryManagerLoggingEvent", "-1")

    with open('example.ini', "w") as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

# Проблема тут! Пытаюсь добавить строку, а функция просто перезаписывает содержимое раздела [General] 
def abc():

    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('example.ini') # я так понял лишнее наверное.
    config['General'] = {'abc': '1'}

    with open('example.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)

# Блок ткинтера, к делу не относится.
root = Tk()
root.title("SSEMC")
root.geometry("950x550+300+200")
root.resizable(False, False)
Button(root, text='get_config()', command=get_config).place(x=260, y=80)
Button(root, text='create_config()', command=create_config).place(x=260, y=160)
Button(root, text='abc()', command=abc).place(x=260, y=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Для того ,чтобы добавить данные в файл не перезаписывая его ,вы должны поменять параметр **w**(write) на **a**(append).*

```py
with open('config.cfg', 'a') as f:
     f.write('\nваши данные')
```

После выполнения этого кода, в файл добавиться новая строка c текстом 'ваши данные'.
Документация по `open`: **[здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)** , [тут](http://pythonicway.com/python-fileio)

Comment: Спасибо, а может еще подскажите.  При добавлении строки в файл Регистр не сохраняется config.set("General", "iStoryManagerLoggingEvent", "-1") == istorymanagerloggingevent = -1

Comment: write за(до)писывает в файл все что вы ему передадите. Скорее всего у вас что-то не так с возвращаемыми данными (из функции). Выводите что вам возвращает функция и смотрите.